# Grails - Ajax submit not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, grails

i'm trying to update a div when a form is submited, but it seems that I am forgetting something.

here's my html:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
    <head> 
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />        
        <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formEntrada">
            <label>Evento: </label>
            <g:select from="${listaEvento}" name="evento_id" optionValue="nome" optionKey="id"  noSelection="${['':'Selecione...']}" required="true"/><br><br>                        
            <label>Participante: </label>
            <input type="text" id="codigo" onkeyup="pesquisa(event,'/eventoEntrada/pesquisar')" value="${participante?.id}" size="15px"/>&nbsp&nbsp
            <input type="text" value="${participante?.nome}" size="50px" disabled required="true">               
            <input type="submit" value="Adicionar">            
        </form>
        <div id="divList">  
            <g:render template="list"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here's my JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formEntrada').submit(function () {        
        alert("evento_id+participante_id");
        var evento_id = document.getElementById("evento_id").value;
        var participante_id = document.getElementById("participante_id").value;        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/eventoEntrada/entrada',
            data: {"evento_id": evento_id, "participante_id": participante_id},
            dataType: 'text',         
            success: function (data) {
                $("#divLista").html(data);
            }
        })       
    });    
});
```

and this is the method:

```
def entrada(){         
    EventoEntrada entrada = new EventoEntrada()        
    entrada.setEvento(Evento.get(params.evento_id))
    entrada.setParticipante(Pessoa.get(params.participante_id))

    println params.evento_id
    println params.participante_id

    entrada.hora_entrada = java.sql.Time.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()))
    entrada.saida_antecipada = false
    if (!entrada.validate()) {
        entrada.errors.allErrors.each {
            println it
        }
    }else{
        entrada.save(flush:true)
        def listaParticipante = EventoEntrada.list()
        render (template:"list", model:[listaParticipante:listaParticipante])
    }
}
```

when i submit the form i get the url ".../.../eventoEntrada/index?evento_id=X&participante_id=Y"
why am i missing?

thanks!

Comment: Instead of passing as this `{"evento_id": evento_id, "participante_id": participante_id}` in ajax data use `$('#formEntrada').serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Ajax url is the problem. you can try to give controller Name and action instead of giving path.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#formEntrada').submit(function () {               
    var evento_id = document.getElementById("evento_id").value;
    var participante_id = document.getElementById("participante_id").value;        
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "${createLink(controller: 'controllerName', action: 'entrada')}",
        data: {"evento_id": evento_id, "participante_id": participante_id},
        dataType: 'text',         
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divLista").html(data);
        }
     })       
  });
});
```